# How to check checkbox multiple to give checked attribute in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to checked checkbox if user has permission i want checkbox is checked.

> HTML

```
    <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let permission of permissions">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input id="checkout-{{permission.id}}"
               name="permissions[]"
               (change)="selectedChange(permission.id)"
               [(ngModel)]="selected[permission.id]"
               type="checkbox"
               value="{{permission.id}}">
        <label for="checkout-{{permission.id}}">{{permission.name}}</label>
     </div>
   </div>
```

> UserGroup

```
export class UserGroup {
  id: number;
   name: string;
   description?: string;
   permissions = [];
   created_at?: Date;
   updated_at?: Date;
}
```

> Permission

```
export class Permission {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
}
```

In the Html how to give checked attribute to input when userGroup.permissions = Permission.id

I have try this in component.ts but is not working is checked all checkbox.

```
for (let permission of response.permissions){
   this.selected[permission.id] = true;
}
```

Can anyone fixed it? or It have other way?
Thank for help.

---

```
[ {id: 11, name: "create-customer", display_name: "Create Customer"},
  { id: 12, name: "edit-customer", display_name: "Edit Customer"},
  { id: 13, name: "list-customer", display_name: "List Customer"},
  { id: 14, name: "delete-customer", display_name: "Delete Customer"},
]
```

Comment: can you post response.permissions array

Comment: wjhat do you want to do

Comment: I want to update user.On UI i want to checkbox is checked if user permission column is match with permission table